# Adding Update changeset in dml format updated value get by select query

Tags: postgresql, yaml, liquibase

I want to add changeset to update the table column value in yaml format and updated value is fetched at runtime via select query;

```
UPDATE table SET groupid=(select id from group where groupname='star') WHERE studentid=(select studentid from student where name ='abc');
```

yaml format

```
 - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: abc
      changes:
         - update: 
             tableName: table
             columns:
               - column:
                   name: groupid
                   value: (select id from group where groupname='star')
             where: studentid=(select studentid from student where name ='abc')
```

but it is not working for me

Comment: yes liquibase changeset in yaml format

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer

```
- changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: abc
      changes:
         - update: 
             tableName: table
             columns:
               - column:
                   name: groupid
                   valueComputed: (select id from group where groupname='star')
             where: studentid=(select studentid from student where name ='abc')
```